# Jquery how to create tags in a text area?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to give my users a text area in my web application and within a text area they can add words and when they hit the space button on the keyboard the word would become a tag. Each word itself would not have a space. What I am trying to do is very similar to the Tags section in Stackoverflow. I dont need autocomplete or anything of that nature.

As I start to develop this feature, I am thinking, I would capture the keyboard space event and a single word before that would become highlighted and an x would appear at the end and if they click x that word would be deleted from the text area.  Any ideas, what event sh

```
if (event.which != 0 && event.charCode != 0)
```

{

}

Answer (score 2):

I would probably bind to keyup, then check for space and if it is space I would create a div above the textarea that will have a clickable 'X', something like this (obviously you need some css to make it look nice and you need a container div above your text area with height auto to append your tags to instead of the body tag):

```
$("#foo" ).bind( "keyup", function() 
{
  if (event.which == 32)
  {
     var thisTagText = $('#foo').val();

     $('body').append('<div class="myTag">' + thisTagText + '<div onclick="removeTag();">X</div></div>'); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I almost sure I saw such plugin. Google "jQuery plugin" and you will find that it is already implemented for you...

Answer (score 0):

Did your answer get cut off?

Anyway, use something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="tags"></div><input type="text" id="tags-input"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
var tagsInput = $("#tags-input"),
    tags = $("#tags");

tagsInput.keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 32) { // when space bar is pressed
        var tag = $("<span>", {html: this.value, class: "tag"});
        var removeTag = $("<span>", {class: "tag-delete"});
        tag.append(removeTag);

        tags.append(tag); // add span to div

        removeTag.click(function(){
           tag.remove(); //delete tag
        });

        this.value = ""; // clear value
    }
});
```

I'll leave it up to you to style it.

Comment: If it was aimed at me, no it did not get cut off, I just thought giving a hint is enough, the person asking sounded like they can write the code themselves :)

Comment: @Martina yes, the question *was* aimed at you. :) It just seemed like you didn't finish your last word, and you didn't include your braces in your code snippet.